# Selecting rows in DF in Pandas where a value is larger than the mean(by function)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to see how I could grab all the rows of data in a df where the numerical value (in a float) is greater than the mean of that specific column.

Currently using UCI data base on wine quality - trying to show all wines with a chloride count higher than the mean - so my column would be 
`df.chlorides`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logical indexing with

```
df[df['chlorides']>df['chlorides'].mean()]
```

`df['chlorides']>df['chlorides'].mean()` will return a Series of `True` and `False` which pandas can use to select the relvant data:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
Name: chlorides, dtype: bool
```